# After upgrade to SP2010, home page error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, upgrade

I upgraded to SP 2010 from SP2007. When go to "http://domain.com/Pages/Default.aspx" it is giving me below error. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Copy the correlation id and search in the logs. That will tell you the exact problem

Comment: can you browse to different pages? i.e settings.aspx, also check in pages library if their is any page contain the special characters...check this http://www.sharepointpitstop.com/2014/08/the-file-or-folder-name-contains.html

Comment: one more thing to check https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2a668d3e-73ca-4f2c-9135-6c51fb2a6c04/page-error-the-file-or-folder-name-contains-characters-that-are-not-permitted-please-use-a?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Comment: Yes, I can go to settings.aspx page. I can still go to some subsites. not root page.

Comment: Still not able to remove this error. How can I use default provided masterpage in sp2014?